# Best practice to resize DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [window.scroll function freezes firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12428754/window-scroll-function-freezes-firefox)

I'm working with project where I have to resize a lot of **DOM** element and wondering how to optimize it.

Now I'm everything doing with **jQuery** resize method, but maybe there is more effective way to do it.

Now my problem is that then I'm resizing window it's starts to lag till all calculations are done, because it's resizing inner holder elements to fit it's holder.

Maybe it's better to use pure **javascript** rather then **jQuery** resize method?

Thanks in future.

Comment: http://paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Comment: So with this link you want to say that is better in this case to fire resize once rather then fire every time then it's changed dimensions?